# scala import package object without package name

Tags: java, scala

How does this code work?

[PackageObject.scala](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/blob/master/modules/common/src/main/PackageObject.scala#L277)

```
package lila

object makeTimeout {
  implicit val large = 5
}
```

[Socket.scala](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/blob/master/modules/socket/src/main/Handler.scala#L12)

```
package lila.socket

import makeTimeout.large
```

`lila.socket` package imports `makeTimeout.large`, but it doesn't use `lila.makeTimeout.large`.

Comment: The `Timeout` class is from Akka and probably used in some calls to Akka API that are made from `Socket.scala`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't, but your minimized example is different from the original code.

In the original code `makeTimeout` is defined inside a trait [WithPlay](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/blob/master/modules/common/src/main/PackageObject.scala#L93), and that's later inherited by the package object lila, defined in [package.scala](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/blob/master/modules/socket/src/main/package.scala#L7), and that makes `makeTimeout` a member of package `lila`.

Note that you could make your code compile if you broke down the package declaration in two lines:

```
package lila
package socket
```